# How to access name tags in avalon dock data template

Tags: wpf

I have used media element in another app to play videos with the same implementation and it works as expected but whenever I put my control in my Avalon dock data template I get this error message "The name'VideoControl' does not exist in the current context on `VideoControl.Play()`  even in this same app it I put my controls outside the Avalon dock tags it works as expected.

```
<DockPanel Name="df"  Grid.Row="2" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" LastChildFill="True"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True" WindowChrome.ResizeGripDirection="TopLeft">
    <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockManager" AnchorablesSource="{Binding Tools}" DocumentsSource="{Binding Files}" ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ActiveDocumentConverter}}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
            <localController:PanesTemplateSelector>
                <localController:PanesTemplateSelector.PreviewViewTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <MediaElement Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top ="40" x:Name= "VideoControl" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" ></MediaElement>
                            <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,13" Name="PlayButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="PlayClick">Play</Button>
                            <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,0,0,13" Name="PauseButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="PauseClick">Pause</Button>
                            <Button Height="23" Margin="191,0,186,13" Name="StopButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Click="StopClick">Stop</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </localController:PanesTemplateSelector.PreviewViewTemplate>
            </localController:PanesTemplateSelector>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager>
</DockPanel>
```

C# Class:

```
public class PanesTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate PreviewViewTemplate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Template Selection
    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        //Creates a new collection of layout content
        var itemAsLayoutContent = item as LayoutContent;

        if (item is PreviewViewModel)
            return PreviewViewTemplate;

        //Returns selected template
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that an expected behavior? Accessing a control inside datatemplate by name is tricky. Use

```
ParentControl.FindName("VideoControl") as MediaElement
```

to retrieve your control

Comment: Could you clarify what ParentControl is? What namespace can I get it from? or are you suggesting for me to traverse through my controls?

e.g `var obj =  object.object.object.FindName("VideoControl") as MediaElement`

because in MainWindow.cs I tried `var obj = this.FindName("VideoControl") as MediaElement`

But the obj came back as null

Comment: ParentControl will be whose datatemplate you are setting.

Comment: the data template doesn't seem to have a valid parent because the data template sits inside the Avalon dock tags I will try to find an MVVM solution.